# Bootstrap Datepicker not showing calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get bootstraps date picker working for a little while now and it seems I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

I have the bootstrap.datepicker.js in the correct folder and am calling the class like so in my main js.

```
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();​
```

and my input looks like this

```
<input type='text' class='form-control date-picker datepicker dates col-md-3' name="" value="" data-date-format='mm/dd/yyyy' />
```

What am I missing?

To help show what is happening, I've created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/75JgV/2/

Comment: @TheLittlePig I did...

Answer (score 3):

Just alternate

Your   `$('.datepicker').datepicker();` has to be after the JS component

**fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/75JgV/3/

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your jsfiddle example is that the

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();​
```

code has to go after you include the jquery, so put it in the end of your js

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker();​
```

since your input has this class.

Comment: Still doesn't work...it doesn't matter what I call the class.

Answer (score 0):

your input should have class the same as you defined in JS

so it should look like this

`<input type='text' class='datepicker form-control date-picker  dates col-md-3' name="" value="" data-date-format='mm/dd/yyyy' />`

Comment: That was a mistype here on my part. The input has the right class. It does in the jsfidle as well.

Answer (score 0):

Run when all page loaded:

```
$(function(){
 $('.datepicker').datepicker();​
});
```